# php mysql_query returns nothing after insert (and nothing is inserted either)

Tags: php, mysql

I've got the following code:

```
    <?php
  if(!empty($error_msg))
   print("$error_msg"); 
  else
  { 
   require_once("../include/db.php");

   $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
   if (!$link) 
    print('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   else
   {      
    $sql = "insert into languages    values(NULL,'$_POST[language]','$_POST[country_code]');";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    print("$sql<br>\n");
    print_r("RES: $res");
    mysql_close($link);
   }
  }
 ?>
```

In one word: it does not work. mysql_query doesn't return anything. If I try the same
query within php_myadmin, it works. It does not insert anything either. Also tried it as
user root, nothing either. Never had this before. Using mysql 5.1 and PHP 5.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: echo $sql, and post here the results..

Comment: `Always` define the columns you're inserting.  The way it's setup now if your structure changes your query will break.  Don't make more work for yourself down the road.

Comment: there is probably some error in your query..

Comment: insert into languages values(NULL,'NETHERLANDS','NL');

Comment: data type are char(30) and char(5)

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_query` will return a boolean for INSERT queries. If you `var_dump` `$res` you should see a boolean value being printed. It will return TRUE for a successful query, or FALSE on error. In no cases it ever returns NULL.

In addition, **never pass input data (e.g.: $_POST) directly to an SQL query**. This is a recipe for SQL injection. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on it first:

```
$language = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO language SET language='$language'";
```

And don't forget to quote your array indices (e.g.: `$_POST['language']` instead of `$_POST[language]`) to prevent E_NOTICE errors.

Comment: There will be no warning for unquoted array index inside strings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Comment: @andre: You're right. I was actually mentioning it because I used it outstring quotes. However, I think you're better off quoting it anyway for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a database so the system knows which database to run the query on...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Without selecting a database, your data will not be inserted

Comment: +1 I think we all missed that one. Good call. Just a note, it's not mandatory. A query like `INSERT INTO database.languages` would work too (something OP didn't do though).

Comment: If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed

Comment: @mooizo: The database link is generated by `mysql_connect`, not `mysql_select_db`. You have to define what database to use in some way.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query returns a boolean for INSERT queries. If used in string context, such as `echo "$res"`, `true` will be displayed as `1` and `false` as an empty string. A query error has possibly occured. Use [mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql_error) to find out why the query has failed.

```
$sql = "insert into languages    values(NULL,'$_POST[language]','$_POST[country_code]');";
```

This is very bad practise, as a malicious user can send crafted messages to your server (see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)).

You should at least escape the input. Assuming your column names are named 'language' and 'country_code', this is a better replacement for the above code:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO LANGUAGES (language, country_code) VALUES ("%s","%s")',
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country_code'])
   );
```

For a description of the mysql_real_escape_string function, see the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string). For beginners and experienced programmers, this is still the best resource for getting information about PHP functions.

Instead of using `$_POST` directly, I suggest using the [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function instead. It's available as of PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

With an `INSERT` query, mysql_query returns true or false according as the query succeeded or not. Here it is most likely returning false. Change the line `print_r("RES: $res");` to `print_r("RES: ".(int)$res);` and most likely you will see it print `RES: 0`.

The problem may be that MySQL expects a list of column names before the `VALUES` keyword.

Also, you appear to be inserting POST variables directly into SQL - you should read up on SQL injection to see why this is a bad idea.

Comment: +1 although I prefer var_dump to (int) cast because var_dump shows you exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

--I retract the quote comment, but still not good to directly insert $_POST values.--

Second, I don't think i've seen print_r quite used like that, try just using an echo.

And mysql_query is only expected a boolean back on an INSERT, what are you expecting?

Comment: The whole string is a double-quoted string, so that will not be a problem. The single-quotes are literal characters to PHP.

Comment: "this:" meaning you have no value? Does a select return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Now ive got this:

$language     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
                $country_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country_code']);

```
            $sql = "insert into shared_content.languages (id,language,country_code) values(NULL,$language,$country_code);";
            $res = mysql_query($sql);

            print("$sql<br>\n");
            var_dump($res);
            print(mysql_error());
            mysql_close($link);
```

And the output:

insert into shared_content.languages (id,language,country_code) values(NULL,NETHERLANDS,NL);
bool(false) Unknown column 'NETHERLANDS' in 'field list'

Comment: $language     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
    $country_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country_code']);
          
    $sql = "insert into shared_content.languages values(NULL,'$language','$country_code');";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);